# Find the tangent line that passes through the point that doesn't lie on the given line

Tags: analytic-geometry, curves

> Find the equation of the tangent line to the curve
>   $$2x^2-4xy+y^2-2x+6y-3=0$$
>   that passes through $(3,4)$.

I think I found the slope of the tangent line at some point $(x_0,y_0)$:
$$y_0'=\frac{2x_0-2y_0-1}{2x_0+2y_0-6}$$
But I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Now find the line from $(3,4)$ to $(x_0,y_0)$; its slope should be $y_0'$ for it to be tangent.

Comment: @Chrystomath it's $$y=\frac{y_0-4}{x_0-3}(x-3)+4$$ So the slope is $$\frac{y_0-4}{x_0-3}$$ should be equal to the one above. And also $(x_0,y_0)$ lies on the curve, so I have 2 unknowns and 2 eqtn bu I don't think this will look solvable :)

Comment: `x0:3;` `y0:4;`
`ratexpand((2*x*x0-2*(x0*y+x*y0)+y*y0-(x+x0)+3*(y+y0)-3)^2-(2*x^2-4*x*y+y^2-2*x+6*y-3)*(2*x0^2-4*x0*y0+y0^2-2*x0+6*y0-3));`
`factor(%);`
$- (x - 3) (2 y - 7 x + 13)$

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Could you, please, tell little about this equation in code. I think I don't get it, sorry

Comment: I use [Joachimsthal's notation](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/JoachimsthalsNotations.shtml) to find the pair of lines that are tangent to the hyperbola from $(3,4).$

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Thanks. It seems a useful thing to study next :) And could you please, tell me what software did you use to factorize?

Comment: [Maxima CAS](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given conic is $$S(x,y)=2x^2-4xy+y^2-4x+6y-3=0$$
Two tangents can be drawm to a coinc from and outside point %(3,4)%, the Eq, of pairs of tangents is given as $$T^2=SS'^2,$$
Where  $$T=2*3x+4y-2(4x+3y)-(x+3)+3(y+4)-3=0 \implies y-x-3=0$$,
$S'=S(3,4)=4$, then the equation of pair of tangents is
$$(y-x-3)^2=4(2x^2-4xy+y^2-4x+6y-3) \implies 3x^2+3y^2-10xy+2x+18y-21=0 \implies (y-3x+7)(3y-x-3)=0$$
So the Eqs. of required tangents are: $y-3x-7=0,~~~ 3y-x-3=0$

Answer (score 1):

Given the quadratic

$$
Q\to 2x^2-4xy+y^2-2x+6y-3=0
$$

A generic line passing by $(3,4)$ can be written as

$$
L\to \cases{x = 3+\lambda v_x\\ y = 4 +\lambda v_y}
$$

now the intersections between $Q$ and $L$ can be obtained substituting $x,y$ from $L$ into $Q$ and solving for $\lambda$ or

$$
\lambda^2+2(v_y-v_x)\lambda +2v_x^2+v_y^2-4v_x v_y=0
$$

and

$$
\lambda = \frac{2(v_x-v_y)\pm 2\sqrt{v_x(7v_x-2v_y)}}{2}
$$

but at tangency, the solution should be unique so

$$
v_x(7v_x-2v_y)=0\Rightarrow \cases{v_x = 0\\ v_y = \frac 72 v_x}
$$

and the tangent lines are

$$
L\to \cases{x = 3\\
y = 4 +\frac 72(x-3)}
$$

Attached a plot

[image]

Comment: The way the problem is set up, you're missing the second tangent, which happens to be vertical.

Comment: Thanks. Now it is fixed.